# WQL WMI Query to watch for newly created files

Tags: file, wmi, wql

The following query should return a set of files that were created to the G drive in the folder test.

I am having trouble getting the following WMI query to work:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE 
TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Drive = 'G:' AND 
TargetInstance.Path = '\\test\\'
```

The wbemtest utility gives me the following error:

```
Number: 0x80041017
Facility: WMI
Description: Invalid query
```

Thanks!

Comment: The WQL looks ok, maybe your are using the wrong method to execute the query (the wmi events must be executed using the [ExecNotificationQueryAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [ExecNotificationQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods ). can you show your source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in the event class name, ie. __ InstanceCreationEvent should be __InstanceCreationEvent. Other than that you shouldn't use the LIKE operator in the query because it will force WMI to search your machine for all files that have 'test' as one of their parent directories. Better to use the exact path.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the error. I am going to update the query to include this modification though.

Comment: You get the same error when you use the correct event class name?

Comment: Me neither, sorry, I tested your updated query in wbemtest.exe and it works for me regardless of the drive and path exist or not.

Comment: Am I running the wbemtest wrong? All I do is open wbemtest, click connect (namespace is root\cimv2), type in my query and then click apply.

Comment: I opened wbemtest.exe, connected to root/cimv2, clicked the 'Notification Query...' button, pasted your query in the textbox and clicked Apply

Comment: When I click the Notification Query button instead of the Query button it works! What is the difference?

Comment: The Notification Query button is for event queries and the Query button is for Select queries. Glad you solved it

Answer (score 1):

This is giving you Invalid query error as you are runnign this as a query, but _*instancecreationEvent or all subClass of "*_InstanceOperationEvent" must be called as NotificationQuery.

Thanks.